# Подставить к артикулу данные с другого листа

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Вкладка 1
Содержит колонку A - в который артикулы
Содержит колонку B - в который потенциальные артикулы
Содержит колонку C - в который потенциальные артикулы

Вкладка 2
Содержит колонку A - в который артикулы
Содержит колонку B - в который артикулы2
Содержит колонку C - в который артикулы3

Когда, вставляем в колонку A (Вкладка 1) артикулы, в Вкладке 1 (колонки B и C) проставляются потенциальные артикулы с Вкладки 2 (колонки B и C)

Вторая вкладка получается выполняет роль базы данных.
Первая вкладка, колонка A выступает иннициатором.

Записали артикул в A1 (первая вкладка), макрос забирает значения B и C со вкладки 2 и копирует (заполняет) соответствующими данными во вкладке 1.

Спасибо.

Comment: Тот макрос который вы напишите самостоятельно. Почитайте правила этого сайта. **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.**

Comment: это не учебное задание

Comment: Это для вас оно кажется не учебным, но для людей которые хоть немного разбираются в программирование - задача на уровне учебной. так что хоть чуть потрудитесь самостоятельно. =)

Answer (score 0):

Если это не учебная, но  рабочая задача и макрос необязателен, для столбцов B, C используйте функцию `ВПР`:

```
=ЕСЛИ($A2<>"";ВПР($A2;Лист2!$A$2:$C$1000;2;);"")
=ЕСЛИ($A2<>"";ВПР($A2;Лист2!$A$2:$C$1000;3;);"")
```

Comment: Что-то делаю не так http://prntscr.com/m3ta1c

Comment: @Kevus, у вас, видимо, англоязычная версия excel, в ней названия функций отличаются, в частности вместо `ВПР` используется `VLOOKUP`

Comment: Да, правда, версия ENG.=IF($A2<>"";VLOOKUP($A2;Лист2!$A$2:$C$1000;2;);"") Тоже не помогает. http://prntscr.com/m3tja7

Comment: Для английской версии замените точку с запятой на запятую. Для гаратии после номера столбца - **2;)** и **3;)** - впишите явно ноль: **...2,0),"")** и **...3,0),"")**